# Shiva Gita in English with commentaries from eminent Philosophers

Tags: shiva, shaivism, gita

Shiva Gita is less known Gita (song) found in Uttara Kanda of Padma Purana. The Siva-Gita begins with episode from the Ramayana epic, where Rama is despondent over the loss of Sita. I found Shiva Gita from [here](http://www.vrindavana.net/academy/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/SivaGita-I.pdf) but this document has no commentaries from Philosophers.

Can anyone provide me complete Shiva Gita in English with commentaries from eminent Shaiva or other Philosophers.

Answer (score 4):

The Tirunelveli District Central Library in Tamil Nadu has the original book in sanskrit with Englsih translation by Sri P.K. Sundaram published by the Centenarian Trust in 1997. The Trust itself does not seem to have a copy of the book (neither the digital nor the printed one).I got a photocopy of the book from that library through the very sincere efforts of one Sri Muthukrishnan, who was an Assistant Librarian there. The cost of the photo copy of the book (including spiral binding in 2013 was Rs 155. You could locate this library though google search if you are serious about the book. 
Mr.Jayakumar, Librarian, Tirunelveli District Central Library,
2/32 North Highround Road, Palayamkottai, Tirunelveli, Tamil Nadu-627002
India Telephone: 0462-2561712

You could post your query for the book with the following details and address it to Sri Jayakumar, Libraian at the following website link

http://tirunelveli.tnpubliclibraries.gov.in/index.php/Contact-Us/S.-Jayakumari.html

The CALL NUMBER OF THE Siva Gita BOOK by P.K.Sundaram in this library is:  Q23:25 N7  and it is in the LLA category of collections. SUNDARAM P K
The Library's record says that it was published by Giri Trading Agency (it has branches in many parts of India, but the information is wrong. It was published by the Centenarian Trust)
SIVA - GITA 97 - GIRI TRADING AGENCY 1997

Comment: it is also available in archive.org

Answer (score 1):

#### Quoting from a Ph.D. research thesis - "[Śiva Gītā - A Critical Study](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/essay/shiva-gita-study)"

> ##### [1.6.0. Available works on Śiva Gītā](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/essay/shiva-gita-study/d/doc425963.html)
>
> - There is a gloss on Śiva Gītā titled Śivagītātātparyaprakāśikā by His Holiness Jagadguru Parama Śivendra Sarasvatī.<sup>**4**</sup>
> - Yet another work Śiva Gītā Bhāșyam was authored by Śrī Śțăgagiri Jagadguru śrīmad Abhinava Nșsimha Bhārati Svāmi.<sup>**5**</sup> [**Only Sanskrit Work**]
> - The third work is in Grantha character with the translation of Sanskrit verses **in Tamil**.<sup>**6**</sup>
> - There is another one publication of Śiva Gītā by the Nirnaya Sagar Press, Bombay.<sup>**7**</sup>. [**Only Sanskrit**]
> - There is a Śiva Gītā with **Hindi translation** of verses.<sup>**8**</sup>.
> - There is a recent work with Tamil translation with meanings written by Anandanāciyāramma.<sup>**9**</sup>
> - Another translation of Śiva Gītā in English is by Prof P.K.Sundaram.<sup>**10**</sup> [**The Only English work with commentary**].
> - It is learnt that there is a translation of Śiva Gītā into the Italian language by Mario Vallauri.<sup>**11**</sup>

###### Since this is a research work, we may be at least 95% sure that they would quote (or at least make a passing reference to) all the extant & non-extant work available in reference to the Śiva Gītā.

###### Therefore, the above-given list seems like the complete extent of all the works which are available on the Śiva Gītā as of 2010 (when the Ph.D. thesis was published).

---

**Footnotes:**

- [4]: Printed in 1906 by The Vani Vilas Press, Srirangam and the author was the 57th Pontiff of the Kāmakoti Pitham from 1539-1586.
- [5]: Published by Śrňgeri Saradā Pītham in 1962 and the author was the 24th Pontiff from 1599-1622. 
  Buy the Book @ [here](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/shri-shiva-gita-bhashyam-nzh074/)
- [6]: Authored by Śrī Muthukumaraswamy Gurukkal from Jaffna, Sri Lanka.
- [7]: This book is published in 1909 vide prof. P.K.Sundaram's Śiva Gītā- introduction P-iv 
   [Archive Link](https://archive.org/details/Qcqh_shiva-gita-with-tika-nirnaya-sagar-press-1886-mumukshu-bhawan-collection)
- [8]: Published by Gangāvişņu Śrī Krşņadās, Kalyan, Bombay – authored by Pandit Jvālaprasād Misra-1994
  Read the Hindi Translation from the [Archive here](https://archive.org/details/shiv-gita-pt.-jwala-prasad-mishra)
- [9]: Published by Śrī Indu Publications, T. Nagar, Chennai in 2004.
- [10]: Published by The Centurian Trust, Chennai in 1997 following the commentary called Bāla-nandini by Hari Pandita. [**Archive Link for the English Translation**](https://archive.org/details/siva-gita-1997)
- [11]: Vide SG-English commentary (Centurian Trust) Introduction p-v.

---

### Overall, it seems like not much work is available on Śiva Gītā either in commentary or translations thereof. Even the English Translation or commentary seems scant, with only one located by the Ph.D. scholar.